# tkinter sharing instance variables between classes

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I have created an application which has only 1 big class that wrap all of functions. The code run smoothly as it should be.

The code can be divided into sections such as: GUI, pure block codes to handle tasks.

I want to seperate the original class into 2 classes, 1 will be the GUI for application and the other is block code that handles tasks.

The problem is that when I do that, 2 classes use the other's instance variables. How can I fix this, please help, thank you.

Example of the original class:

```
Class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'first variable'
        self.var3 = 'third variable'
    def method1(self):
        self.var2 = 'second variable'
        print(self.var3) 
    def method2(self):
        print(self.var2)  
        self.method1()
```

Here is the example of the 2 new classes (I just split them up and haven't modify anything):

```
Class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'first variable'
    
    def method1(self):
        self.var2 = 'second variable'
        print(self.var3)  # <-- var3 is belonged to class Core

Class Core:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 'third variable'
    def method2(self):
        print(self.var2)  # <-- var 2 is belonged to class GUI
        self.method1()  # <-- method1 belonged to class GUI too
```

Comment: how about You keep all the variables in the __init__ method? which should have been the case anyways. so when You split some variables are just not being used

Comment: Putting instance variables in ```__init__```  is just about declaring it, right?  'cause I have to use them later in class's methods though

Comment: sort of like that (it is not mandatory since You can define them in other functions but it just throws a PEP error or sth (the code still runs)) but in this case it will just help You, but actually the answer here is also a great way of going about it

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the solution:

```py
class GUI:
    var2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.var1 = 'first variable'

    @staticmethod
    def method1():
        GUI.var2 = 'second variable'
        print(Core.var3)  # <-- var3 is belonged to class Core


class Core:
    var3 = None
    
    def __init__(self):
        Core.var3 = 'third variable'

    @staticmethod
    def method2():
        print(GUI.var2)  # <-- var 2 is belonged to class GUI
        GUI.method1()  # <-- method1 belonged to class GUI too
```

You should make your variables and methods `static`. You can read more about static methods and variables in `python` here: [Are static class variables possible in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/are-static-class-variables-possible-in-python)